# Google Maps - How do you align a MarkerImage so that the bottom left points to the lat/lng of the Marker

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

Given w = width of image and h = height of image, how do I set it so that the bottom left corner of the image specified in url points to the latitude and longitude defined by the marker?

```
...
'icon': new google.maps.MarkerImage(url,
  new google.maps.Size(w, h),
  new google.maps.Point(?, ?),
  new google.maps.Point(?, ?)
),
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
...
'icon': new google.maps.MarkerImage(url,
  new google.maps.Size(w, h),
  new google.maps.Point(0,0),
  new google.maps.Point(0,h)
),
...
```